# Copy Sheet to Another Workbook - Path Error

Tags: vba, excel, path

I am trying to write a code to copy a worksheet, to an open workbook. But I am getting a path error at the end.

The code looks like this right now;

```
Sub Storyboard_Ekle()
    Dim DosyaSec As Office.FileDialog

    Set DosyaSec = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

   With DosyaSec

      .AllowMultiSelect = False
      .Title = "Lütfen yeni eklenecek Storyboard dosyasini seçiniz."
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook", "*.xlsm"
      .Filters.Add "Excel Workbook", "*.xlsx"
      .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

      If .Show = True Then
        YeniSB = .SelectedItems(1)
      End If

Dim YeniStoryBoard As Workbook
Dim AnaDosya As Workbook
Dim YeniStoryBoard_Sheet As Worksheet
Dim AnaDosya_Sheet As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set AnaDosya = ThisWorkbook

YeniStoryBoard.Sheets("Storyboard").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Kunye")  '-> This gives error

YeniStoryBoard.Close

Set YeniStoryBoard_isim = Sheets("Storyboard")
YeniStoryBoard_isim.Name = "StoryboardXXYYZZ"


   End With
End Sub
```

I am going to make some modifications on the code onwards, but this doesn't work properly. :(

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are the workbooks in the same directory?

Comment: look like YeniStoryBoard_isim & YeniStoryBoard are two different variables witht he latter never being set

Comment: @DougCoats - exactly the same thought :)

Comment: It's my bad, I didn't set "YeniStoryBoard" at the codes. How can I set that with "YeniSB" at the codes? As you can see, YeniSB gives me the path and file name. How can I use it as a workbook object in the codes?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one-line code to solve your case:

```
Public Sub TestMe
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Storyboard").copy after:= ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Kunye")
End Sub
```

It should work. Then start checking what does not work in your case line by line. I guess that the problem is that after `Dim YeniStoryBoard As Workbook` you do not set it. Thus, it is `Nothing`.

Comment: It's my bad, I didn't set "YeniStoryBoard" at the codes. How can I set that with "YeniSB" at the codes? As you can see, YeniSB gives me the path and file name. How can I use it as a workbook object in the codes?